# How to convert an array from psql databse into a list of strings?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, psql, formtastic

I'm building a quiz app for a final project and it's due next week I have been struggling on a issue trying to convert an array into a list of strings.

Questionnaire Model:

```
class Questionnaire < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :categories

end
```

Chose_answer.html.erb

```
<h1>Congrats You Hit The Choices Page!</h1>

<%= semantic_form_for @questions.choices do |c| %>

  <%= c.inputs do %>

    <%= c.input :choices, :as => :check_boxes , :collection => 
   [@questions.choices].map(&:inspect).join(', ') %>

  <% end %>

<% end %>
```

Questionnaire Controller:

```
class QuestionnairesController < ApplicationController

  def index

    @questions = Questionnaire.find(params[:category_id])
    #params[:category_id]= <%=category.id%>
    @category = Category.find(params[:category_id])
    @videos = VideoClue.find(params[:category_id])
    ###This finds all the questions from the question table by their category_id. Whenever I select a category, it matches the question related to the category

    render :show
    ###render :show Renders Html page
  end

  def choose_answer
    # binding.pry
    @questions = Questionnaire.find(params[:id])
    #params[:id] = /:id  = /1


    render :choose_answer
  end
```

Questionnaire table seed:

```
Questionnaire.create({question: "In that year did MTV (Music Television) 

premiere and what was the first music video the channel aired?", choices:

["1982 Michael Jackson 'Bille Jean'", "1984 Madonna 'Like a virgn'", "1981

The Buggles 'Video Killed The Radio Star'"], correct_answer:"1981 The 

Buggles 'Video Killed The Radio Star' ", category_id:1})
```

@question.choices returns

```
["1982 Michael Jackson 'Bille Jean'", "1984   

Madonna 'Like a virgin'", "1981 The Buggles 'Video Killed The Radio Star'"],
```

I want to convert "choices" into a list. I want to use formtastic to turn them into multiple choice How should I do that? Please I need someone to help answer this because I really want to complete my project on time and have it working.

Comment: Your association should be `belongs_to :category`

Comment: The name of my database table is called categories. Why should it be category?

Comment: belongs_to association should always be singularize and not pluralize

Comment: Where do you use `@question.choices` in your actual code? Also when you do `@questions = Questionnaire.find(params[:category_id])` are you looking for questionnaires (not questions) that belong to a specific category? Does `@questions` return anything?

Answer (score 0):

Check the documentation [here](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/justinfrench/formtastic/Formtastic/Inputs/CheckBoxesInput). You can pass an array as collection:

`<%= c.input :choices, :as => :check_boxes , :collection => @questions.choices %>`

Comment: what is `@question.choices` returning? You can check with sample data `<%= c.input :choices, :as => :check_boxes , :collection => ["1982 Michael Jackson 'Bille Jean'", "1984 Madonna 'Like a virgin'", "1981 The Buggles 'Video Killed The Radio Star'"] %>`

Comment: It returns the array itself.

Comment: When I did [@questions.choices] it returns |check box| ["1982 Michael Jackson 'Bille Jean'", "1984 Madonna 'Like a virgin'", "1981 The Buggles 'Video Killed The Radio Star'"]